# javascript date increment

Tags: javascript

I want to set a text box with a date (in dd/mm/yyyy format)  14 days ahead to current date in javascript . can any one help me regarding this ?

Comment: What have you done so far? What isn't working?

Answer (score 9):

This should do it:

```
var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+14);
```

then

```
document.getElementById(YOUR_TEXTBOX_ID).value = myDate.getDate() + "/" + 
  (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is a handy script for all kinds of JavaScript date manipulation. I've used it to make many date-based interfaces, including calendar controls.

Answer (score 0):

Like Deodeus suggested, use Date.js:

```
var myDate = Date.today().add(14).days();
document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = myDate.toString('dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the function to increment date by one day in javascript.

```
function IncrementDate(date) {         
     var tempDate = new Date(date);
        tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() + 1);
        return tempDate;
}
```

Function calling...

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var IncrementedDate =  IncrementDate(currentDate);
```